# Rating bar with custom style shows bad images

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am using below icons for my custom rating bar:

[image]

[image]

and use below codes:

my custom drawable:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_list_item_wstar" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_list_item_wstar" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_list_item_ystar" />
</layer-list>
```

my custom style:

```
   <style name="YellowRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ic_ratingbar_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">22dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">22dip</item>
</style>
```

my rating bar code:

```
    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    style="@style/YellowRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isIndicator="false"
    android:rating="3.7" />
```

but it has not a good result and my result looks like below:

[image]

**EDIT**

the size of icons is 17X17pixel. I set min and max size to `17dp` and the black lines go smaller and finally when I set it to `11dp` the black lines disappear.

why I need to set the min and max size to less than the icon actual size??!!

Comment: What if you just try to use @drawable/ic_list_item_wstar in your custom style?

Comment: I used only ic_list_item_wstar and the proble is live yet

Comment: Can it be that your @drawable/ic_list_item_wstar is 9-patch drawable (has .9.png at the end)? Then it will behave like this.

Comment: no they are not 9-patch . they are .png files

Comment: How did you solved this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I do not solved it in a good way yet. but setting width of rate bar to smaller size helped me. for example in this case the image size is 17 and I set the rate size 11.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue of dragging lines when using *custom star images in rating bar*.

A simple solution to this is to **`keep a padding of 1px to the star image`**

For instance, consider the two images below;

[image: Image1 32x32px] - Image1

[image: Image2 36x36px] - Image2

Image1 is the original image of *32x32px*, which gives the dragged effect, whereas,

Image2 is the same image but having a padding of 1px which makes the image size to *36x36px* and removes the drag effect.

> why I need to set the min and max size to less than the icon actual size??

That's because you have placed your (17x17px) images in the `drawable-hdpi` folder and for hdpi, 17px = 11.33dp.

What you could do is place the images in the `drawable` folder and then setting the **`minheight`**`and`**`maxheight`**`to`**`17dp`** will do the job.
However placing images in the drawable folder, is not the right way to do it.

The best practice is to put different pixel sizes of image, in each *drawable-mdpi*, *drawable-hdpi*, *drawable-xhdpi* and *drawable-xxhdpi* folders.

Hence, `17x17px` image should be placed in `drawable-mdpi` folder.
So (in your case), the corresponding image sizes to be placed in the folders are,

```
drawable-mdpi - 17x17px
drawable-hdpi - 25x25px
drawable-xhdpi - 34x34px
drawable-xxhdpi - 51x51px
```

and

```
<item name="android:minHeight">17dp</item>
<item name="android:maxHeight">17dp</item>
```

For calculating the image sizes in different folders, you could use [**dp to px conversion** method](http://androidpixels.net/)

Answer (score 2):

### **Basic of Rating Bar in Android Studio**

[Simple Rating Bar without Material Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Fhs.png)

**How to add?**

I. In your build.gradle add latest appcompat library.

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X' // where X.X.X version
}
```

II. Make your activity extend android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    ...
}
```

III. Declare your RatingBar inside any layout.xml file.

```
<RatingBar  
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**

### How to style?

**

I. Declare custom style in your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">  
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

II. Apply this style to your RatingBar via android:theme attribute.

```
<RatingBar  
    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
    android:rating="3"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

if you like this and want more **Material Design Stuffs** http://exandroidstudio.blogspot.in/2015/11/rating-bar-material-design-tips.html

Comment: How is this answer related to this question about shapes?

Answer (score -1):

the fastes idea is to add your extra 1dp padding into your image.
Do it in PhotoShop or any image editor.
After having this extra space everything should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21707592)

Comment: I don't agree it's what I did and it's fixing problem.